Web app not working properly when launched with Visual Studio Code debugger
I am working on a web project that uses React and Redux. I am trying to put together a debug configuration for it. This app also relies on the presence of an Apache Zookeeper Docker container in the background.
Here is the configuration I use:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "Launch Server",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "pnpm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "start:WebUI"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch UI",
            "url": "http://localhost:3222",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

Problem: When I launch the UI, Firefox opens and the UI starts, but it displays an error. Opening the console with F12 shows, in the networking tab, that it cannot connect to Zookeeper. But if I start Firefox manually and enter "localhost:3222", then everything is working as expected and the UI can connect to Zookeeper. The problem only happens when the browser is started by VSC.
Please note that I also tried with Chrome, and was facing the exact same issue.
